# How to register multiple versions of assembly that reference different .Net frameworks?

Tags: .net, delphi, com, registration

I'm having a very strange problem registering a .Net 4.0 assembly, classes from which are then created and used in a Delphi application.  I'll try to explain as best as I can.

Some background:
- In previous versions of our product, we built against the .Net 3.5.
- Our assembly version was set to '1.0.*.*'.

Our customers can, and sometimes do, have two versions of our product installed at a time. Because of this, we re-register our assemblies when the customer switches versions.  For simplicity, lets say they have two versions of our assembly in the registry. The registry for a single registered class in the assembly looks like this:

CLSID
  {GUID Class is registered as.}
    InprocServer32
      1.0.3979.26322
      1.0.3980.20802

At any given time, the keys under InprocServer32 look like this:

- (Default) - mscoree.dll
- Assembly - NameOfAssembly, Version=CurrentRegisteredVersion,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
- Class - NameOfAssembly.ClassName
- RunTimeVersion - v2.0.50727
- ThreadingModel - Both

Under these circumstances, everything works fine.  We can register either version of our assembly, and that version will be loaded by our application and will work properly.  The problem occurs when one of the registered versions of the assembly is built against .Net 4.0.

In that case, the RunTimeVersion for one will be set to v2.0.50727 as it is above, and the other will be set to v4.0.30319.

Here's where things fall apart... once an assembly is registered against the 4.0 framework, only one version of our product will function properly, and it's the version that is built against whichever assembly has a larger assembly version number.

I know I'm probably not being clear on that last part, so let me simplify further.  Say we have two versions, built against the following runtimes:

- Assembly Version 1, Runtime 3.5
- Assembly Version 2, Runtime 3.5

... in that case, I can register either version, and the currently registered version will function properly.

But if I have the following:

- Assembly Version 1, Runtime 3.5
- Assembly Version 2, Runtime 4.0

or

- Assembly Version 1, Runtime 4.0
- Assembly Version 2, Runtime 3.5

... then if I register and run version 1, I'll receive OLE errors in the Delphi app attempting to create an instance of the class.

If I register and run version 2, everything works fine.
If I register version 1, and manually delete the version 2 key, version 1 will work fine.
If I register version 1, and manually change the RunTimeVersion of version 2 to match version 1, version 1 will work fine.

Any ideas on what's causing this, or a way to fix and still have multiple versions in the registry at the same time?  It's as if the current registered version isn't taken into account once the assembly is registered against more than one framework, and instead the highest assembly version is used no matter what.